Protection from liability for actions of employees
A video game developer ("Smoke") has created a popular online game which features various chat features. Smoke hires a number of chat moderators to manage this, including "Joe Gooner". After a few days, Mr. Gooner's supervisor observes him sexually harassing child players. His actions are both illegal and against company policy, so the supervisor fires him immediately. Assume that Smoke had no way to reasonably know about Mr. Gooner's perversion prior to the incident, despite doing their due diligence with references and reviewing his social media accounts.
Is there anything Smoke can do to protect themselves from legal liability for the moderator's actions? If not, is there anything they can do in case another employee does something similar in the future?
I am especially interested in the law as applies to companies in the United States, but viewpoints from other countries are welcome and encouraged.

Related: Under these circumstances, can a company be sued for the actions of an employee?

@WeatherVane It's related, but not exactly what I'm looking for. In my scenario, there is no willful non-enforcement (among other smaller considerations).

Worth pointing out, as usual, that the law isn't uniform everywhere and the law that applies could influence the result. Precisely which place's law applies (Smoke's HQ, the location of the employee, the location of the children) is hard to know. The TOS might control. Also, the stakes in a few days of online chat communications would be much lower than the stakes in an in person child abuse case. It's not entirely clear that the actions of the employee would be illegal apart from violating company policy. It's probably not a crime and a tort theory isn't obvious although there might be one.

@ohwilleke: It depends on the facts of the case. I believe the US has a number of laws pertaining to the sending of "harmful" (obscene) materials to minors, which would be one kind of "sexual harassment" that our hypothetical employee might commit. I would prefer not to go into any more disturbing hypotheticals than that, but I'm sure you can imagine a few other crimes someone might commit that would broadly fall under that label.

@Kevin There might be. But it is pretty hard to have liability from merely a chat.

Pro-active management and insurance
As an employer, Smoke is vicariously liable for the acts and omissions of its employees in the course of their employment. While sexually harassing children is clearly not a function of their employment, moderation is, so the overall course of action is in the course of their employment—they were not on a frolic.
Smoke should take all reasonable steps to prevent, detect, and respond to employees' acts and omissions that could expose them to liability. This is part of a formal, documented, and ongoing risk assessment, elimination, and mitigation program. This offers the best chance of avoiding the potential liability, and if it happens despite Smoke's best efforts, it may be enough to defend against a lawsuit.
In addition, you buy insurance to cover the risk.

There have been cases holding that an employee handbook prohibiting employees from engaging in the conduct that gives rise to the liability bars vicarious liability. One WY law 10th Circuit case, https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/ca10/21-8009/21-8009-2022-03-11.html, involved a truck driver who while filling the company truck up with gas (clearly not a frolic) lost his temper and assaulted another gas station customer causing serious injuries. But the winning employer's employee handbook for his employer specifically prohibited assaulting people on the job.

@ohwilleke you would probably need to advance evidence that the employee was given the handbook and was aware of its contents. That’s why documenting training and inductions is so important.

@ohwilleke It seems crazy that they have to explicitly tell employees not to engage in clearly illegal activity while on the job, it should go without saying. But I guess that's a consequence of our litigious society.

@Barmar what about a trucking company that pressures it's drivers to complete routes quickly, leading to speeding / driving whilst tired etc? Those are clearly illegal, but the company only cares about avoiding liability for any negative consequences of those things, it doesn't really want them to stop happening.

@Barmar The result wasn't necessarily wrong, but the reasoning was pretty crazy which is what made the case memorable. With only rare exceptions, two people can reach an agreement that limits their liability to a third-party. The law involving criminal acts by employees is subtle and hard to predict. Presumably, that provision was put there because Swift (one of the largest trucking companies in the U.S.) probably had similar incidents come up in the past. Their main motivation was probably to make clear that the trucker who did that could be fired for cause for unemployment purposes.

@Caleth Conduct that is part and parcel of the job like that probably couldn't be avoided with an employee handbook. There wouldn't be vicarious liability for a speeding ticket (and the threat of a driver losing his commercial driver's license for points is a big concern) but a policy that employees aren't allowed to be negligent when driving wouldn't get the company off the hook.

@ohwilleke that's my point. "explicitly tell employees not to engage in clearly illegal activity" is not sufficient to avoid all liability.

Last sentence is really important.  Any question of "how to protect against liability?" should be answered in some part by "get insurance".

france

Is there anything Smoke can do to protect themselves from legal liability for the moderator's actions?

From a legal point of view, no. Practically, yes.
Article 1384 of the civil code, fifth paragraph:

Les maîtres et les commettants [sont solidairement responsables] du dommage causé par leurs domestiques et préposés dans les fonctions auxquelles ils les ont employés


Masters and business partners [are jointly liable] of damage caused by their servants and subordinates within the functions in which they were employed

This has been interpreted to mean that the employer is liable for anything that was done by an employee on their work time and in the workplace, even if the actions were clearly illegal or outside the employee’s delegated authority. The most striking example is Cour de cassation, 17 mars 2011, 10-14.468, where a music teacher sexually assaulted and raped students during lessons (and was condemned and sentenced criminally for that); the employer (and its insurance) are found liable for indemnity. (The refund scheme is a bit complicated - in fact the victims had already been indemnified by the state’s "fund for crime victims", so that is the entity party to the lawsuit asking for repayment.) The employer (and insurance company) may in turn sue the employee for repayment, but that is only worth it if the amount in dispute is large enough to justify legal fees and small enough that the employee can pay a significant part of it, so that does not happen often.
While Smoke cannot entirely remove the risk that a rogue employee causes them legal issues, they can (and, in some cases, must) take insurance against civil liability. They can also organize work in such a way that no single employee can cause a tremendous amount of civil liability; train employees to detect and avoid potentially-dangerous situations; etc.

"small enough that the employee can pay a significant part of it" -- this is not necessary -- only that the absolute amount the employee can pay (including their personal liability coverage) is large enough to justify legal fees. If an employer had to pay a 100M judgment, it is worth spending 100k on legal fees to recoup 1M from an employee, even though that's only 1% of the judgment.

germany
In Germany, like in many other countries, in principle the employer is liable for mistakes made by an employee while performing their duties:

The obligor is responsible for fault on the part of their legal
representative, and of persons of whose services they avail themselves
in order to perform their obligation, to the same extent they are
responsible for fault on their own part. The provision of section 276
(3) does not apply.

BGB (German civil code), sec. 278
This is referred to as Arbeitgeberhaftung ("employer liability"). However, this liability is limited by, among other things, BGB (German civil code), sec. 831:

A person who deploys another person to perform a task is liable to
provide compensation for the damage that the other unlawfully inflicts
on a third party when carrying out the task. Liability in damages does
not apply if the principal exercises the care required in business
dealings when selecting the person deployed and, to the extent that
they are to procure devices or equipment or to manage the business
activity, in such procurement or management, or if the damage would
have occurred even if this care had been exercised.

So, in plain language:

The employer is generally liable for employees' unlawful acts, no matter whether they were accidental (mistakes) or intentional.
However, this only applies to actions required or directly connected to carrying out their assigned tasks.
Also, the employer can avoid liability by exercising care when selecting the employee, or proving that the damage would have occurred even if this care had been exercised.


So, Mr Gooner's actions would probably fail both of the criteria listed above:

his actions (harassment) were not directly connected to their task, and
the employer has demonstrated sufficient care when selecting the employee

Of course, a court might see this differently - so there is no way to tell for sure. For example, there is some debate on how closely linked the employee's assigned task and the unlawful act need to be (see e.g. Die Haftung für den Verrichtungsgehilfen, § 831 BGB - some opine that it is enough if the assigned task provided a helpful opportunity for the unlawful act, even if the act itself was not part of the assigned tasks).
